# SQL Server : removing 0x00 characters from a string

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, encoding

I am comparing 2 strings, where one of them is assigned by me, and the second one is taken from a table.

The one from the table, after I converted it to hex, shows '00' signs like in example `1400210068008100`. I wish to remove those empty characters during string comparison. I tried using `replace` and `trim` but that didn't help me, the only thing that did work was using `LIKE`, but that is not safe.

So my question is, how can I remove unwanted "00" characters from the string I fetch from a table?

Comment: Do you want to remove all trailing zeroes, or something else?

Comment: all null characters

Comment: How do you distinguish `00` as null from a legitimate sequence in a number?  This question doesn't feel right.

Comment: is It always "00" at end or it can be "000"/"0000"?

Comment: always 00 at end

Comment: It also seems that you are reading an NVARCHAR field into some kind of client datatype that isn't processed with the UTF-16 encoding of the Unicode character set. Please show the field definition (including collation if it is actually VARCHAR) and the client code. Please also tag the question of the relevant language and data access technology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably mixing `VARCHAR` (1 byte extended ASCII) and `NVARCHAR` (2 byte unicode) encoding. Check this out:

```
SELECT CAST(N'hello' AS VARBINARY(MAX)) --look at the N in front of the literal!
      ,CAST( 'hello' AS VARBINARY(MAX))

"hello" as NVARCHAR: 0x680065006C006C006F00 
"hello" as VARCHAR:  0x68656C6C6F
```

Cast your binary to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, cast this to `VARCHAR(MAX)` and then to `VARBINARY(MAX)`.

### UPDATE

It might be a better idea to expand the string **without** the doubled zeros to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and compare them on unicode base. Otherwise you might get in troubles, if your string contains special characters (like `0x14` ...)

Comment: Your answer is more relevant : +1